# Set local variable for current row in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use a variable from a row that is being selected from one table in a SELECT function targetted towards a second table. I tried doing this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sender = $row['sender_id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$sender'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row2['user_uid'];
    }
}
```

I understand that this is not how you set a variable for each row, but I have no clue how it should be done otherwise. At the moment it only displays the username of the sender of the first notification in my inbox database, not the rest.

If anyone knows how to set a variable per row, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use a `JOIN` on initial query ?

Comment: @TGrif I think that would work, but how do I refer to the value that I just joined? $row['friendships.sender_id'] or $row['users.user_id']?

The code is "INNER JOIN users ON friendships.sender_id=users.user_id"

Comment: It seems not a good idea to make SQL query in a while loop. In addition, you assign `$result` to your second query, that's why you get just the first result. Show us your initial query.

Comment: I would suggest that you ask a new question.  Provide sample data and desired results.  Doing nested loops in PHP with SQL queries is very rarely the best approach.